# Logout problem after few clicks

Tags: security

The sandbox is on CS18, which has been upgraded to Summer 14 is showing very strange bahaviour.

Now, in my sandbox, users are kicked out (redirected to the login page) after a few clicks.

Anyone is having idea for the same?

Regards,
Amrish

Comment: Do you have more than one sandbox? Reason I ask is if the users are opening multiple tabs in the same browser to different sandboxes on the same instance, I have experience something like this.

Comment: Anything custom to your org authentication that play a role: Custom domain, SSO,  .. ?

Comment: Have checked Session settings in security controls..

Comment: We have a multiple sandboxes, but if we have opened only one sandbox in the same browsers still it is getting timed out

Answer (score 4):

This commonly occurs when you have implemented custom links or buttons that have a hard coded id. When the sandbox is then copied from production these hardcoded links refer out to a different salesforce org, and so when users click them they are requested to login. This fact is not apparent to users and so it can be concerning.

Check that all custom links, sidebar links, web tabs, custom buttons or any other place where a custom link may exist. Hardcoded items will need to be corrected as an operational process during sandbox instantiation.

Comment: We are facing this issue not on clicking of custom links and buttons, it is when we click on setup sidebar links.